# Creating a MongoDB Builders filter using the '.AnyIn' method for a nested array

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using the MongoDB.Driver (v2.8.1) in my C# application, and working with the following JSON document structure:

```
{
  Entries: Array
    0: Object
      Categories: Array
        0: String
        1: String
        ...
    1: Object
      Categories: Array
        0: String
        1: String
        ...
    ...
}
```

In my application code, I have a string list which contains various strings:

```cs
List<string> CategoryFilters
```

I need to create a filter which will include all database entries where 'Entries[any].Categories' contains any of the strings within my CategoryFilters list.

I have tried using the following, but to no avail:

```cs
Filter = Builders<MySchema>.Filter.AnyIn("Entries.$[].Categories", CategoryFilters);
```

I have no problem creating the following filter when my JSON document's Categories array is not nested within another array:

```cs
Filter = Builders<MySchema>.Filter.AnyIn(a => a.Categories, CategoryFilters);
```

However, I am unsure how to apply the above logic to my nested array example above.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply remove the **all positional operator $[]** from the field path to target nested arrays. so your filter would look like this:

```cs
Builders<MySchema>.Filter.AnyIn("Entries.Categories", CategoryFilters);
```

**update:**
you can use `$elemMatch` if you'd like to do it in a type safe way.

```cs
Builders<MySchema>.Filter
                  .ElemMatch(x => x.Entries,
                             y => CategoryFilters.Any(z => y.Categories.Contains(z)));
```

Comment: you're most welcome. and i've updated the answer with a strongly-typed way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
var builder = Builders<Category>.Filter;

// Filter by field with list of desired values
var idListFilter = builder.In(u => u.Id, new [] { 10, 14 });
```

Or Try this way:

One Filter:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("status", "D");
var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

And Multiple Filters:

```
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = builder.And(builder("CategoryFilter", 1), builder("CategoryFilter", 2));
var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Link: *https://gist.github.com/a3dho3yn/91dcc7e6f606eaefaf045fc193d3dcc3*

*Link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/*

*Link Multiples: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/*